# How to handle multiple managed beans with the same name in JSF2.0

Tags: jsf, facelets, managed-bean

I'm learning JSF/facelets. Say I have two ManagedBeans with same name but in different packages. When beans used in a xhtml, it seams JSF will resolve the backing bean in the alphabet order. If the team have many guys, how to avoid that one will not override the others backing bean , since they may use the same name for their beans. Is there any best practice in this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not prefixing your managed bean names with the package name?

Example:

```
package myPackage;

@ManagedBean(name="myPackageMyClass")
@ViewScoped
public class MyClass { .. }
```

Comment: Matt, Sure I can. Since I'm new to JSF, I'm wondering if it's a best practice. Actually I've tried to package them to seperated libraries(.jar) as composite component resources, hoping they will resolve the classes in the same lib, but with no luck: The managedbean is resolved to the first one they meet in the classpath regardless whereever it is in.

Answer (score 1):

If the bean classes have the same class name, then it's already a poor design from the beginning on. Ask yourself, why do they have the same class name? Do they have the same responsibilities? Why not just make it one class? Or do they have different responsibilities? Give the classes a different name.

Comment: Say we're building a large enterprise app which need hundreds of JSF pages. Those pages server different purpose(responsibilities). We assign the web layer development to many different guys and ask them put their backing beans to their own packages(e.g., Toms goes to web.beans.tom, Allens goes to web.beans.allen). But since there're so many beans, chances are that some beans being given the same name, even though their have different responsibilities,in different packages.

Comment: A decent IDE will create warnings and runtime the container will to